# Second FOR loop is being skipped

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17

I am not getting any compile-time errors, but whenever i run the program the second FOR loop gets skipped and the program stops. i put a cout after it and that executed, but the second for loop was still skipped.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    int numbers[5];
    for(int i; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    for(int i; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you initializing `i` in either loop?

Comment: It is a good practise to initialize variables and not rely on implementation of a language, e.g., variables `i` in the two for loops

Comment: you are lucky that the 1st loop is even running tho...

Comment: your code compiles without error, because you need to use dedicated flags to make the compiler diagnose this as error: https://godbolt.org/z/4W6oT3. To be fair, gcc seems to have problems to detect use of uninitialized variables in conditions (or I am not finding the right flags)

Comment: Got to wonder where this error comes from. We see uninitialised for loop variables all the time on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
 int i;
```

That declares an `int` named `i` without initializing it. Its value is said to be indeterminate. There is not much you can do with an indeterminate value, for example

```
int x = i;
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). When your code has ub then almost anything can happen. You could get no output at all, or some gibberish, or Hamlet printed on the screen (though this happens rarely).

You are not initializing the counter in both loops. That the first one appears to work is purely a matter of luck. Or rather bad luck, because appearing to work is the worst incarnation of wrong code.

Many guidelines suggest to initialize variables as soon as you declare them. Often this is put another way: Only declare a variable when you can initialize it. In any case, seeing `int i;` should make you shiver in fear ;).

Your loops should look like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    std::cin >> numbers[i];
}
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    std::cout << numbers[i] << "\t";
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to iterate the whole container you can use a range based for loop which eliminates the chance for such mistake completely:

```
for(auto& n : numbers)
{
    std::cin >> n;
}
for(const auto& n : numbers)
{
    std::cout << n << "\t";
}
```

---

Note that use of initialized variables can be diagnosed by most compilers. With `-Wall -Werror` clang [refuses to compile your code](https://godbolt.org/z/4W6oT3). Unfortunatly gcc fails to diagnose the issue in your code (while it quite reliably can diagnose cases such as `int i; int x = i;`). Hence, you should pay attention to warnings, and to make sure you cannot miss them you can treat them as errors.

Comment: For consistency, `std` should appear both in `cin` and `cout`

Comment: @zois I chose consistency with OPs code, but yeah right

Answer (score 2):

In both of the `for` loops, try replacing `int i;` with `int i = 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia: [Unintialized variable in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable)

> A common assumption made by novice programmers is that all variables are set to a known value, such as zero, when they are declared. While this is true for many languages, it is not true for all of them, and so the potential for error is there

In C++/C when you don't initialize a variable, it gets the current value from memory or variable stack, you can't expect a especific  value.

It's considered a good practice to always initialize variables in C/C++. So just change your code to:
`for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` for **both loops** and it will works.

### Extra

Your IDE should warn you about unitialized variables, check plugins like [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) or any kind of linter for c/c++

Comment: "_it gets the current value from stack_" This is not really true, because (a) not all variables are allocated on the stack, and (b) there is no "current value" to speak of, just indeterminate memory, which might have been used for something else a microsecond ago, might be zero, or might be anything else. We can't rely on any notion of a "current value". It's just UB

Comment: Good point, changed the text to be clearer. You cannot expect any specific value. so my explanation was kinda confusion.